# How to style SVG <linearGradient> with Tailwind CSS when using `fill="url(#a)"`?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, tailwind-css

I have seen [@adamwathan](https://twitter.com/adamwathan)'s live streams & he does `className="w-5 h-5 text-white" fill="currentColor"` to style an SVG through Tailwind.

How can I do the same for `linearGradient`?

I have the following SVG:

```
import React from 'react'

export const LinearGradient = () => (
    <svg className="w-5 h-5" viewBox="0 0 17 17" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="92.034%" x2="50%" y2="7.2%" id="a">
                <stop offset="0%" />
                <stop stopOpacity="0" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <circle
            className="text-white"
            stroke="currentColor"
            fill="url(#a)"
            cx="8.5"
            cy="8.5"
            r="6"
            fillRule="evenodd"
            fillOpacity=".8"
        />
    </svg>
)
```

How do I style `linearGradient` in SVG that uses `fill="url(#a)"` perfectly? I can't change `fill="currentColor"` as it will lose reference to `id="a"`.

The original SVG is at https://www.sketch.com/images/icons/mac/monochrome/17x17/circle.gradient.linear.svg

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To style the `linearGradient` colors you can use the `stop-color` attribute on the `<stop>` elements.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<svg class="w-32 h-32 text-blue-500" viewBox="0 0 17 17" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="92.034%" x2="50%" y2="7.2%" id="a">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="currentColor" />
        <stop stop-opacity="0" offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle stroke="currentColor" fill="url(#a)" cx="8.5" cy="8.5" r="6" fill-rule="evenodd" fill-opacity=".8" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work without the `div`? I put `className="w-5 h-5 text-pink-400"` locally & that works fine unlike in JSBin. Even `circle` isn't working on JSBin but works locally.

Comment: That was my bad, I forgot to change `className` to `class` in my snippet (it doesn't use React unlike your code). I've updated the code.

Comment: Weird, I tried doing it in JSBin & it didn't work so I kept the `div` as is. Glad, it's working now :)

Comment: Absolutely ingenious!

Answer (score 8):

You can also create variables from your `tailwind.config.js` that you can use in your SVG.

Here is an example of how to do it inside a Laravel 8 project.

## tailwind.config.js

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

module.exports = {
    theme: {
        colors: {
            blue: {
                300: colors.blue[300],
                500: colors.blue[500],
            },
            ...
```

## resources/css/variables.css

```
:root {
    --color-blue-300: theme('colors.blue.300');
    --color-blue-500: theme('colors.blue.500');
}
```

## resources/css/app.css

```
@import './variables.css';

@import 'tailwindcss/base';
...
```

## resources/views/svg/my-svg.blade.php

```
...
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:var(--color-blue-300);" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:var(--color-blue-500);" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
...
<path style="fill: url(#grad1);" ...
```

Then, i'm using in another view (ex: my-layout.blade.php) `@include("svg.my-svg")`.
Using this instead of `<img src="my-svg.svg"...` allow tailwind's classes to impact the svg.

If you really want to use `<img>`, a concept is to use controller to build your svg and return a view with `response(..., 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml');`. I did something like that where i set the color in the url `<img src="my-svg.svg?fill=blue-500"...` *(and it work successfully with tinyMCE 6 which disallow the usage of svg)*